# Radio buttons do not show database info, and also do not disable when another radio button is selected

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called "step".   In my step model, I allow the user to create a multiple choice question.  As a result I have four database columns, choice one through four.  I am trying to take these database columns and put them in the form of a question with radio buttons.  My problem is that @step.choice_one does not show (nor do the others).  Additionally, the radio buttons show, but they are not related to each other, as it allows me click on each one without the others disabling.  Any help would be truly appreciated.

```
<%= fields_for :steps do |f| %>
    <div class="multipleChoice">
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_one, "1)" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_one, @step.choice_one, :checked => true, class: 'icheck' %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_two, "2)" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_two, @step.choice_two, class: 'icheck' %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_three, "3)" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_three, @step.choice_three, class: 'icheck' %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_four, "4)" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_four, @step.choice_four, class: 'icheck' %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If the radio button value is what is in the database currently, how do they get set initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a radio button group for a set of 4 distinct fields rather than 4 choices on one field. So Rails is giving each a distinct `name` attribute.

Try giving each `radio_button` the same name: 'step', for example:

```
<%= fields_for :steps do |f| %>
    <div class="multipleChoice">
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_one, "1) #{@step.choice_one}" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_one, @step.choice_one, {name: 'step', checked: true, class: 'icheck'} %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_two, "2) #{@step.choice_two}" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_two, @step.choice_two, {name: 'step', class: 'icheck'} %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_three, "3) #{@step.choice_three}" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_three, @step.choice_three, {name: 'step', class: 'icheck'} %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :choice_four, "4) #{@step.choice_four}" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :choice_four, @step.choice_four, {name: 'step', class: 'icheck'} %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I used `1` through `4` as the values, but you may choose what you wish.

Comment: Thankyou, this works for the radio button selection, but I still have the problem where @ step.choice_one - does not display what is in the database.   If I change the label <%= f.label :choice_one, "1" %> to :choice_one, @ step.choice_one it works fine - but I would like it in the radio button itself not on the label.

Comment: With the above I get: wrong number of arguments (4 for 3).  Alternatively this works but does not feel right: <%= f.radio_button :choice_one, { name: 'step', :checked => true, class: 'icheck'} %><%= @ step.choice_one %>

Comment: @SeanL sorry. I made a correction. It already knows it's "steps" because of the `fields_for` as you originally ahd it. You say it works if you just change the label to @step.choice_one instead of "1)" (and the others)? It would be interesting to see the generated HTML in each case.

Comment: I think what I may be confused on is that I am trying to have @ step.choice_one be next to the radio button.  I think I am realizing that this is not done in the f.radio_button, but in the label itself.  However, now I am struggling to get it to say "1) 50 billion" in which 50 billion is @ step.choice one.   I tried this <%= f.label :choice_one, "1)" @ step.choice_one %> and it does not work

Comment: Ah I got it to work - by doing this:  <%= f.label :choice_one, "1) " + @ step.choice_one %>  I needed the plus sign I suppose

Comment: @SeanL, yes. The `+` concatenates the "1) " and the `@step.choice_one` using string concatenation. And now I understand what you were saying was missing. :) I show an alternate method in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute of the radio buttons **must** match that of the other radio buttons for them to pair up correctly; I don't know ruby's syntax, but I see you using 4 different names everywhere except the `class`, so I suspect you're setting choice_one, choice_two, etc as the `name` :)